# List Intersection

Tags: java, arrays, list, intersection

given two lists of integers with no duplicates. The intersection of the two lists is a list of integers that are in both lists, when i run my program the ouput is wrong, can any one help me to figure out where did i messed up

```
public class  List_intersection {
    public int [] Intersection (int [] tab1, int []tab2) {
        int [] result = new int [7];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i=0; i< tab1.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<tab2.length; j++)
                if(tab1[i]==tab2[j])
                    result[k++]=tab1[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        intersection_Union a= new intersection_Union ();
        int [] tab1= { 4, 7, 12, 6, 17, 5 , 13};
        int [] tab2= { 7, 19, 4, 11, 13, 2, 15};
        int [] res = new int [7];
        res=a.Intersection(tab1, tab2);
        System.out.println(" l'intersection est : " + res);
    }
}
```

Comment: `a` is of type `intersection_Union` code you posted is for class `List_intersection`

Comment: Returning the fixed length array 'result' may result in extra zeros being returned in the result if there are less than 7 intersecting elements. It will also through a array out of bounds exception with more than 7 intersecting elements. Either use a ArrayList or perform a arraycopy to a new result array trimmed to desired size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you can't `System.out.println` an array.

You can use a loop to print out the content of the array.

```
System.out.print(" l'intersection est : ");
for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
  System.out.print(res[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
    intersection_Union a= new intersection_Union();
```

should be

```
    List_intersection a= new List_intersection();
```

Logic in your `List_intersection.Intersection` seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The result of this code will be [4, 7, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0]. I think this is correct, zeros excluding. If the ending 0s are wrong, re-instantiate array of size k and copy all valid members.

Check, you seem instantiating a different class in your `main`. Also, the print statement as it is will not print the contents of the array. Use the `for` loop to print the array members.